# How to access View settings API in order to hide status bar from IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I've looked on the IntelliJ Plugin SDK docs but couldn't find where the API to toggle items under the **View** submenu, such as the `toolbar` or `status bar` visibility, is located?

Something like:

```
ViewAPI.setStatusBarVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API class containing these is `UISettings`.

```
  UISettings.getInstance().setShowStatusBar(false);
```